# Change path of object and wrong bounding rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setBackgroundColor('#ccc');
canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;

var line = new fabric.Path('M100,350 Q200,100 300,350', {
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  objectCaching: false
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 15,
  fill: 'blue',
  lockScalingY: true,
  lockScalingX: true,
  left: 300,
  top: 350
});
canvas.add(line, circle);

canvas.on('object:moving', function(event) {
  var path = canvas.item(0);
  path.path[1][3] = event.target.left;
  path.path[1][4] = event.target.top;
  path.setCoords();
  canvas.calcOffset();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

[show demo on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pngsa4gw/)

When I move circle there is a change path of line. After change path of line I see wrong bounding rectangles.
How I can fix that?
I can just remove line and create again, but maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually recalculate the bounding box, but you have to do by yourself.

So is actually tricky, you need to remove the current pathOffset from path, and then call the internal method to recalculate the bbox.

It works, but being an internal method and a non supported feature, it could be changed in the future.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setBackgroundColor('#ccc');
canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;

var line = new fabric.Path('M100,350 Q200,100 300,350', {
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  objectCaching: false
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 15,
  fill: 'blue',
  lockScalingY: true,
  lockScalingX: true,
  left: 300,
  top: 350
});
canvas.add(line, circle);

canvas.on('object:moving', function(event) {
  var path = canvas.item(0);
  path.path[1][3] = event.target.left;
  path.path[1][4] = event.target.top;
  path.pathOffset = null;
  path._setPositionDimensions({});
  path.setCoords();
  canvas.calcOffset();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```